# How to automate jshint as part of build process?

Tags: javascript, command-line, tfs, rhino, jshint

I want to automatically run JSHINT on all my javascript files as part of our continuous integration environment (actually, probably as part of TFS Gated Checkin, but I'm not sure yet as it will depend on speed).

I tried using **rhino-jshint** like this:

```
java -jar js.jar jshint-rhino.js myFile.js
```

but how can I set the required JSHint options? I know I could list them in a comment at the top of `myfile.js`, but I've got lots of javascript files, and I don't want the options duplicated in all my source files. (Or does JavaScript have an 'include' feature that I'm not aware of?)

I had hoped to pass an `options.js` file in as a parameter on the command line, and then keep `options.js` under version control. But I don't think this is possible with jshint-rhino.js.

Additionally, we are using a [Visual studio extension](http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/) to 'JSHint' all JavaScript files as we save them. But this tool cannot be ran on the command-line. We want the best of both worlds - running JSHint inside Visual Studio and Automated for the CI build, and then without duplicating the options (and indeed keeping the options under version control).

So the question is, how do other people automate JSHint in their development process?

Comment: Is this just a command-line utility that you want to run during the workflow-based automated build?

Comment: @Ed - yes, that sums it up. I am now using SharpLinter, and run the analysis as part of the Post Build Event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are essentially wanting to use a command-line activity inside of the TFS 2010 build process, then it is actually pretty simple.  You'll want to add an `InvokeProcess` workflow activity ([see MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.invokeprocess.aspx)) at the point you want to run the tool.

There is actually a [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805001.aspx) available for how to do this with a different command-line utility but you'll just replace it with your own.  The workflow activity even allows you to specify a set of command-line parameters that you can pass in.

Comment: Thanks for the InvokeProcess link. I'm new to TFS builds and adding a simple command line call as part of the build sequence looks complicated as first glance - but maybe it is simple after all.

Comment: It sure is!  Did this end up solving the problem for you?

Comment: Still calling it as a Post-Build event. It is working and is fast, so I haven't got to the requirement to do it as an InvokeProcess (yet).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check your Javascript while running a TFS build I would recommend having a look at sharplinter:

https://github.com/jamietre/SharpLinter

This contains a executable which allows you to check your Javascript files with JSLint/JSHint. To run this during your TFS build you could create a Code Activity which can be included into your workflow.

This video by Marcel de Vries from the Techdays 2012 goes through the automated build process step by step, and gives a demonstration on how to include your custom activity.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2361

Comment: Indeed we are using SharpLinter. We have a batch file which finds all the javascript files in given a visual studio project, and sends them to SharpLinter. We call the batch file as a post-build event of a visual studio project. We have not yet been able to upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 - we're using 2010.

Comment: That would mean that your code doesn't get checked during a TFS build, but the code only gets checked on your local environment. If this works for you there is no need in changing it, but if you're working with a team it might be worth checking for errors on the actual TFS build. This post was my starting point for integrating sharplinter, so even if it doesn't help you, maybe there are other people whom it might be helpful to :).

Comment: Oh I agree - SharpLinter is great. But this solution is not only for local environments - the TFS build also fails when the PostBuild event fails. Because it builds the project using MSBuild from the command line, and the ostBuild event exists in the project configuration that we use in the TFS build. The solution is working fine for us - a team of approx 10 developers.

Answer (score 0):

Look at both http://gitcasette.com/ and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/meeting-grunt-the-build-tool-for-javascript/